# How to get laravel nova server error message and customize it

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I Want to change laravel nova message when creating , updating and deleting in my custom message.

[image]

Comment: I never used Nova, but If you can't edit them, I would first look at localization https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/localization.html#localization

Comment: This is not sufficient answer for me right now.
I've already used that

Comment: How was that not sufficient? I luckly found a repo on github with published localization and you have that line right there: https://github.com/bahamagician/nova-testing/blob/master/resources/lang/vendor/nova/en.json#L32

Comment: @Nexio Edit the copy in `resources/lang/vendor/nova/en.json` file